# Which video editing software is best compatible with RTL languages?

Tags: editing

I have to do some editing and add right to left text over a video, from past experience I've learned that some programs dont handle well RTL text, so if you can recommend from your experience about one that does it would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use images of the text, just about any program will handle it fine.  I would expect that any professional level product such as Premiere Pro should also handle it fine.  Even in software that doesn't support it, you can often fake it by entering the text and then doing the reveal backwards starting from the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Wiki there are a number of RTL (right to left) and bi-directional text editors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors

First scroll down to the "Right to left (RTL) & bidirectional (bidi) support" chart, which is about 75% of the way down the page. Then compare other features with the other charts such as:

"Overview" (which has cost or free indicated)
"Protocol support"
"Natural language"
"Cross-platform"